# Ubuntu 19.04 nvidia 430 : only one display works at a time

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, lightdm, gdm

sorry to include you in this mess but I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one with this issue:

I have a relatively new notebook with a Ge-force 1050TI. Since I need to be able to run preliminary models requiring cuDNN library, I can not use the ubuntu-drivers but installed the nvidia 430 driver on the Ubuntu 19.04 system.
Drivers work well including cuDNN, but no matter what I try, I can only get either the internal OR an external display to work:
With GDM3 only the internal display works. With Lightdm and xorg only the external display works.

Please someone save me from spending more days with this!
Here is some debug output.Let me know if you need more - I'll do what ever it takes.

```
(base):~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [103c:8519]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [10de:1c8c] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] [103c:8519]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia


(base):~$ lshw -C video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:190 memory:8f000000-8fffffff memory:6050000000-605fffffff memory:6060000000-6061ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:90000000-9007ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:189 memory:6062000000-6062ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.


(base):~$ modinfo nvidia
filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        430.14
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     7CC15950AB2B0F0117C7586
alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        ipmi_msghandler
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       5.0.0-15-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           NvSwitchRegDwords:NvSwitch regkey (charp)
parm:           NVreg_Mobile:int
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_MapRegistersEarly:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_NvLinkDisable:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_GpuBlacklist:charp
parm:           NVreg_TemporaryFilePath:charp
parm:           NVreg_AssignGpus:charp


(base):~$ xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI-0 3840/1050x2160/590+0+0  HDMI-0
(base):~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1050mm x 590mm
   3840x2160     30.00 +  59.94*   50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   4096x2160     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: what steps do you through to light one monitor and what steps for the other?

Comment: in lightdm ONLY the external works not matter if if plug in or unplug the external. In GDM3 the other way round. The debug output above was made running lightdm. The system is out of the box 19.04. Only changes: Blacklist nuveau, install nvidia 430, (install anaconda),

Comment: i really don't follow why are you having to MANUALLY install 430 on an ubuntu 19.04? 19.04 comes with that preinstalled. they're even in effect at the LiveUSB stage. why blacklist nouveau if it's not even installed? this doesn't sound like 19.04

Comment: the preinstalles 430 was not detected by cuDNN (tensorflow). "No compatible GPU found". I have no clue why. I read in the tesorflow github that one should install the nvidia driver manually. But maybe you are right and I should start with the base 19.04 and try to make cudnn work with the preinstalles nvidia driver instead of the other way round. Messy either way. I'll give it another go tonight.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone with the same problem:

I had to make a fresh install and install the ubuntu nvidia drivers. Check the box during installation or: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

The current autoinstalled version that works for me is 418.56 , the 430+ is beta at this point.

To make tensorflow > 1.3 work, install the CuDNN only via Anacona (use conda install tensorflow-gpu instead of pip install tensorflow-gpu).

Now everything around the graphic card works except the s2idle or any suspend/standby/hibernate for that matter. Also appears NVIDIA related but could also be HP Spectre x360 specific. I'll post when I find a solution.